# Executing PowerShell scripts from C# vs System.IO.File.Move for renaming

Tags: c#

What is the most performant, stable and preferred way of renaming files in C#? I am talking about fairly complex regex operations, not just a simple replace and maybe even tens or hundreds of files.

Should I let C# communicate with `powershell` and let it do the renaming for me with some scripts or should I do it differently as shown here:

```
System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");
```

I would appreciate some insights.

**Narrowing down my question**: Should I use C# alone or in combination with powershell for extensive automated file renaming?

Comment: While not an answer, it will be good to look at shell (such as grep, commands provided by OS) that provide this capability because it might well be better in performance.

Comment: "Most performant, stable, and preferred way" each of those is not necessarily the same thing. The most performant may not be stable. "Preferred" is a judgement call depending on details of the situation. I doubt calling out to powershell would be more performant than C#, since the powershell cmdlets are written in C#.

Comment: Are you talking about moving on the same volume or to a different volume? On the same volume, a rename is usually an extremely fast operation since the file contents do not actually need to be copied or moved anywhere. Only the file system needs to be updated with the new path to underlying data.

Comment: it should be moved to the same volume / folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the powershell internal functions. I don't see a benefit of integrating a `.NET`-function.

You could start with something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter $format -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $sourceDir -Whatif
```

The `-Whatif`-parameter will only print out what would be done. It is useful for testing your parameters.

But if you want to use C#, keep in mind to wrap it in a try-catch:

```
try
{
    File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename"); // Try to move
    Console.WriteLine("Moved"); // Success
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
}
```

Comment: But as far I know Powershell in fact using infernal .NET functions. Powershell is not the same like cmd. So if you are coding in C# there is no point to dealing with scripts unless you want use robocopy, but still you don't need PS to do this... Correct me if I'm wrong ;)